# Shortcuts app not loading

Tags: macbook-pro, bug, shortcuts-app

Hey fellas I brought a new MacBook air. When I opened gallery in shortcuts app it shows me a lot of shortcuts but when I click or add those it keeps on loading infinitely. Same happens for my friend in his iPhone.

Is this a issue with me or with the app?